# Rtools with R portable

Tags: r, zip

Hello Fellow enthusiasts,

I use portable version of R for a project in a computer where I have no administrator privilege. I use zip function to encrypt & zip a folder. Apparently computer doesn't have Rtools and I cannot install it. I am wondering how I can point R to look into a local folder where I have Rtools available (with ../bin/zip.exe)
I have tried to add `Sys.setenv(zip="folderpath_of_Rtools/bin"` in Rprofile.site But it is not working.

Comment: You can use `R.bat` or `Rpathset.bat` in the batchfiles distribution: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/batchfiles   Both can work on a machine without Admin privs.   See the documentation in `batchfiles.md` there (or convert it to PDF using `make-batchfiles-pdf.bat` first.

Comment: Also note that R does have an unzip command: `?unzip`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was  posted by OP in a question body. Transfered to separate answer.

After a reboot, the following code works:

```
Rtools.bin="C:\\Users\\User_2\\R-Portable\\Rtools\\bin"
sys.path = Sys.getenv("PATH")
if (Sys.which("zip") == "" ) {
    system(paste("setx PATH \"", Rtools.bin, ";", sys.path, "\"", sep = ""))
}
```